# direct sum and tensor product of representation of lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $(p_1,V_1),(p_2,V_2)$ representation of a lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ on $V_1,V_2$.

I have to prove that:

> $ i)\quad$ the direct sum $p_1 \oplus p_2$ is a representation of
> $\mathfrak g$ in $V_1 \oplus V_2$
>
> $ ii)\;\;\,$ the tensor product $p_1 \otimes p_2$ is a representation of
> $\mathfrak g$ in $V_1 \otimes V_2$

My idea is (by definition of direct sum):

$$(p_1 \oplus p_2)[x,y](v_1,v_2)=\big(p_1[x,y](v_1) , p_2[x,y](v_1)\big)
                       = \big((p_1(x)p_2(y)-p_1(y)p_1(x))(v_1)  ,  (p_2(x)p_2(y)-p_2(y)p_2(x))(v_2)\big).$$

But i dont know how to continue to prove the bracket identity.

Any help about this, and for $ii)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the direct sum we have
\begin{align*}
(p_1\oplus p_2)([x,y])(v_1,v_2) & = (p_1([x,y](v_1), p_2([x,y](v_2)] \\
 & = ([p_1(x),p_1(y)](v_1), [p_2(x),p_2(y)](v_2)] \\
 & = [(p_1\oplus p_2)(x), (p_1\oplus p_2)(y)](v_1,v_2).
\end{align*}

Given two Lie algebra representations $\rho_i:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow V_i$, for $i=1,2$, the tensor product $\rho_1\otimes \rho_2$ is the representation given by
\begin{align*}
\rho_1\otimes \rho_2\colon \mathfrak{g} & \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V_1\otimes V_2), \\
 x & \mapsto \Bigl( v_1\otimes v_2 \mapsto (\rho_1(x))(v_1)\otimes v_2+v_1\otimes (\rho_2(x))(v_2)\Bigr).
\end{align*}
The inner map is first defined on pure tensors $v_1\otimes v_2$, and then is understood to be extended to the whole space by linearity.
A similar computation as above shows that $[(\rho_1\otimes \rho_2)(x),(\rho_1\otimes \rho_2)(y)]=(\rho_1\otimes \rho_2)([x,y])$ for all $x,y\in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: thank you Mr Dietrich Burde..it is cleal about the $i)$...but for $p_1 \otimes p_2[x,y](v_1 \otimes v_2)=p_1[x,y](v_1) \otimes v_2 + v_1 \otimes p_2[x,y] v_2 = 
[p_1(x),p_1(y)](v_1) \otimes v_2 + v_1 \otimes [p_2(x),p_2(y)] v_2 $ $= .....=
$$ [(p_1 \otimes p_2)(x),(p_1 \otimes p_2)(y)]$...i cant find the inside step could you give me the property that i will use..

Comment: Dear Prof. Burde - Well, I found you in the orchestra - you gave too big a hint. Please forgive me if this is too dopy a request. I have been self-studying Lie Theory at a very basic level, primarily using Stillwell's Lie Theory and a bit of Hall's book. It is evident that to go any further, I have to learn somewhat about tensor products. I have made minor inroads into notes by Elkies and Gowers. I am sue my understanding is deficient. Maybe you would please be kind enough to point me to a source(s) where I can learn material so that I can understand your answer here. Thanks and my regards,

Comment: @Andrew You already have found out yourself about tensor products, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307391/what-do-these-tensor-products-actually-mean)! Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) is always a good starting point, with references.