# What do these tensor products actually mean?

Tags: notation, lie-algebras, tensor-products

I have been self-studying tensor products from several sets of notes and numerous posts here. I apologize for what should probably be obvious.

I would appreciate knowing what the following actually mean with a small example of each. (I do know that the $\mathbb{R}$ underset means that that is the field over which scalar multiplication occurs.)

$$\mathbb{C}\,\underset{\mathbb{R}}{\otimes}\,\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$$

$$1\,\underset{\mathbb{R}}{\otimes}\,\tilde{h}_i$$

Thanks

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$? The general linear group is neither an $\Bbb R$-module nor an $\Bbb R$-algebra, so if that's what it is then I too wonder what the tensor product is.

Comment: @Arthur it's the Lie algebra associated with the general linear group.  That is, it's just $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tensor product in this case is being used as an [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars).  That is: $\mathfrak{gl}$ is a real vector space, but we're defining/allowing for multiplication by complex numbers in a "natural way".
$%For ease of writing things down, let's take$
$%n = 2$

The elements of the space $\Bbb C \otimes _\Bbb R \mathfrak {gl}$ are sums of the from $\sum_{i=1}^k z_i \otimes h_i$ where for each $i$, $z_i \in \Bbb C$ and $h_i \in \mathfrak{gl}$.  The trick with the tensor product is that the product is defined to "distribute correctly".  So for instance,
$$
(2 + i) \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0} = \\
2 \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0} + 
i \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0} =\\
2\left[ 1 \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0}\right] + 
i \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0} =\\
1 \otimes \pmatrix{2 & 4\\0 & 0} + 
i \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0}
$$
In fact, what we've effectively defined are matrices with complex entries.  That is, $\Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb R} \mathfrak{gl}(\Bbb R,n) \cong \mathfrak{gl}(\Bbb C,n)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces (and of Lie algebras).

Comment: I know "thanks" is discouraged in comments. But I'll try to slip this through. You always provide such clear and instructive answers. Best regards,

Comment: What can mathematical object "mean"?  What is $\pmatrix{1& 2\\0&0}$ supposed to mean?  I think that you're trying to interpret $(2 + i) \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0}$ as an instruction to the effect of "do something with the objects $(2 + i)$ and $\pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0}$".  However, that's not what's happening here.  For our purposes, $(2 + i) \otimes \pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0}$ is "the thing you get after 'multiplying' $(2 + i)$ and $\pmatrix{1 & 2\\0 & 0}$".